# Node failing after doing npm install on mac

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm working on a intro github lab course and I cant seem to do npm install as it keeps failing. This also happened on another project I was working on

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/me/Desktop/intermediate-node-course/node_modules/bcrypt
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
```

Comment: It's trying to build a C++ module. Do you have Xcode installed and accepted the license agreement?

Comment: yes I have xcode installed

Comment: That doesn't look like the full log.

Comment: I got it to work, I just deleted the package that it was causing the problem from and it seemed to work